# Case insensitive urls for Django?

Tags: python, django

It seems by default django's url solver perform case sensitive search for solving url and differentiate between '/Login' and 'login'. My url patterns are as follows.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.STATIC_DOC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    (r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    (r'^logout/$', do_logout),
)
```

Can anyone please guide me, how to make django urls case insensitive?

Comment: Most solutions here works with views with case insensitive URLs. Such solution has a drawback, that it creates multiple valid URLs for the same page.
That might be bad for SEO, because it divides attention of the search engines.
You might look into redirect middleware solution by @Pandos here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60679483/case-insensitive-urls-in-django-3-0

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Just put `(?i)` at the start of every `r'...'` string, i.e.:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^(?i)admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),
(r'^(?i)static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': settings.STATIC_DOC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
(r'^(?i)login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
(r'^(?i)logout/$', do_logout),
)
```

to tell every RE to match case-insensitively -- and, of course, live happily ever after!-)

Comment: It worked.... Thank you very much... Can you suggest me good resources for learning regular expressions using python?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ if you need free-as-in-free-beer info; http://docs.python.org/library/re.html for Python-specific info; http://books.google.com/books?id=NYEX-Q9evKoC&dq=regular+expression&printsec=frontcover&source=bll&ots=qon_rQMxev&sig=2Z-RDduTVFdL1LeT8mlNq8GTh5U&hl=en&ei=PzbIStutJYqssgPjscH_BQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=12#v=onepage&q=regular%20expression&f=false if you can afford to invest (great book!-).

Comment: Additionally, since the (?i) is a regular express flag, it need not be after the Caret. For example, `(r'(?i)^logout/$', do_logout),` works as well and might be more readable to some.  Other regex flags that can be used within the express are 'L', 'm', 's', 'u', 'x' as discussed under (?iLmusx) at [https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: @ChrisFreeman that's actually not the exact same thing -- in my project it broke reverse url lookups by name when i used `r'(?i)^foo/$'`

Comment: This doesn't work from django 2.0  onwards and produces 

ValueError: Non-reversible reg-exp portion: '(?i'

Comment: How to do this in 2021? When using django  3.2

Answer (score 22):

In Django 2.1, it appears that `(?i)` placed *anywhere* inside the URL regex will cause it to ignore case. However, `reverse()` fails unless the `(?i)` follows the `$` at the end of the regex.

```
from django.urls import re_path, reverse
from django.shortcuts import render

def home_page(request):
    foo = reverse('home_page')
    return render(request, 'home.html')

urlpatterns = [ re_path(r'home/(?i)', home_page, name='home_page') ]
```

raises

```
ValueError: Non-reversible reg-exp portion: '(?i'
```

but runs cleanly with the regex `r'home/$(?i)'`.

Comment: Ran into this while upgrading from Django 1.* to 2.*. Cheers!

Comment: What if I use path instead of re_path?

Answer (score 4):

### Django 2.2 update

According to [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31099):

> Support for inline flags in regular expression groups ((?i), (?L), (?m), (?s), and (?u)) was deprecated in Django 1.11 and removed in Django 2.1

In Django 2.2 adding `(?i)` to the start of a pattern produces this exception:

`ValueError: Non-reversible reg-exp portion`

confusingly, adding it to the end produces this warning:

`DeprecationWarning: Flags not at the start of the expression`

[The new suggested way](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27648) to handle case insensative URLs in Django is to use a [custom 404 handler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views).

FWIW, that ticket also suggests "case-insensitive URLs aren't a good practice", however it doesn't provide any more arguement for this.

There is a package on PyPi called [`django-icase`](https://pypi.org/project/django-icase/) that looks like a good option

Answer (score 3):

`(?i)` might break `reverse`, so here's an alternate solution:

```py
import re
from functools import partial

from django.urls.resolvers import RoutePattern, RegexPattern, _route_to_regex
from django.urls.conf import _path
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured


class IRoutePattern(RoutePattern):
    def _compile(self, route):
        return re.compile(_route_to_regex(route, self._is_endpoint)[0], re.IGNORECASE)


class IRegexPattern(RegexPattern):
    def _compile(self, regex):
        """Compile and return the given regular expression."""
        try:
            return re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE)
        except re.error as e:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                '"%s" is not a valid regular expression: %s' % (regex, e)
            ) from e


ipath = partial(_path, Pattern=IRoutePattern)
re_ipath = partial(_path, Pattern=IRegexPattern)
```

It works for me from Django 3.2, and I don't think it would be broken in 2.0. Both for `include()` and views:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ipath('smartservice/', include('stb_manager.urls')),
    ipath('test/', some_view),
]
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me on Django 4.1

Comment: Worked for me as well when upgrading from django 3 to django 5. Thanks man you're a lifesaver

Answer (score 2):

With Django 2.0 (released in December 2017) the recommended way to use regular expressions for URL-matching is now [`re_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#simplified-url-routing-syntax) instead of `url`:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [   
    re_path(r'^(?i)admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),
    re_path(r'^(?i)something/(?P<somestring>\w+)/$', views.something),
    re_path(r'^(?i)login/$', views.login),
    re_path(r'^(?i)logout/$', views.logout),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also manage this from your view. For instance, if you have a generic.DetailView, you could override **get_queryset** method and set the **slug** value to lower case:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify


class MyModel(models.Model):
    """MyModel

    """  
    # name attribute is used to generate slug
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Name', unique=True)

    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, verbose_name='Slug')

    # override save method to generate slug
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(MyModel, self).save(force_insert=False, force_update=force_update, using=using, update_fields=update_fields)
```

views.py:

```
from django.views import generic


class MyModelDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    """MyModelDetailView

        Detail view of MyObject.
    """

    model = MyModel
    template_name = 'my_models/my_model_detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            self.kwargs['slug'] = self.kwargs['slug'].lower()
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
            pass

        queryset = self.model.objects.filter()
        return queryset
```

urls.py:

```
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url

    url(r'^my_model_detail/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.MyModelDetailView.as_view(),
        name='my_model_detail'),
```

Answer (score 0):

**[2024]** Nowadays, add `(?i)` whether at end or begin of the re_path() function is broke and raises errors.

The only way to accomplish a case insensitive is use a library, or write your own function that verbosely (without using global flags like `(?i)`) make the dirt part of the **reg-expr** specifying. **i.e** to allow the word in `"get"` in `re_path` as `"Get"` or `"gEt"` etc. you can write manually the `reg-expr` -> `"[G|g][E|e][T|t]`.

I wrote a function that achieve it.

```py
def icase(word: str):
  # convert the letter in reg-exp fragment
  icase_reg_exp = ''.join([f'[{c.upper()}|{c.lower()}]' for c in word])
  return f'{icase_reg_exp}'
```

So you can use it at re_path as follow:

```py
url_patterns = [
  re_path(f'{icase("foo")/{icase("get"}', FooModel.as_view(), name=foo_view)
  # ...
]
```