# Is Django Model name case sensitive

Tags: django, django-models

I have this class

```
Class Fruits:


Class fruits:
```

Are they both same or different

I need to pass the  Model name in URL so will it accept if someone enter lowercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is case sensitive, so by extension, Django is too.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515634/case-insensitive-urls-for-django) for making Django urls behave case-insensitively

Comment: my problem is that i need to pass e,g `/admin/login`  , here , i need to pass Admin as the Model name as the postional argument to my view function . will my problem be solved by using (?i)

Comment: You could always title case your model names, then title case the incoming string using .title() so they match

Comment: Are models case sensitive when referring to them via a string, such as in migrations: `model_name='mymodel'`?