# Django model names are case insensitive, right?

Tags: python, django, django-models

If I have `myapp/models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class FooBar(models.Model):
    x = models.BooleanField()

class Foobar(models.Model):
    y = models.BooleanField()
```

and add `myapp` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and do a `syncdb`, I only get `FooBar` model converted to a db table. The `Foobar` model is ignored.

Another strange thing to note is that when we do

```
from myapp import models
```

both `FooBar` and `Foobar` are present as attributes of `models`. However,

```
>>> models.FooBar.__name__
'FooBar'
>>> models.Foobar.__name__
'FooBar'
```

and both are just interfaces to the db table of `FooBar` (by default `myapp_foobar`).

I am asking this question because it seems to me from this that django model names are case insensitive and yet I have not found any documentation stating this and moreover [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6557368/1009979) question was answered to the effect that django model names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 6):

Django model names are not case insensitive, but basically, Django creates a lowercase table name from the app and model names. Thus `FooBar`, which is in `myapp`, will generate a myapp_foobar table, and so will `Foobar`.

Obviously in your example, the names will overlap. Django should warn about clashing table names, but instead, silently ignores clashing models.

To fix this, I suggest you have explicit and distinct table names for your two models. Use the Meta inner class, and set Meta.db_table. See the [Django documentation on models Meta](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/).

Example given:

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    x = models.BooleanField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'myapp_foobar_one'

class Foobar(models.Model):
    x = models.BooleanField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'myapp_foobar_two'
```

In a real world environment, I would *never* have two similar model names in the same app. It is extremely error-prone.

Comment: Even with your code in a brand new project, the problem persists. The `Foobar` does not lead to a new table. It is simply ignored. It would make a lot of sense if this problem was just a consequence of the default table name (app name plus lowercase version model name), but it seems like it is someone else. In practice, I would not use names like this. But it is the principle of the thing that is bothering me.

Comment: It might be related to the Django app registry then. In one page of the documentation, they say "Returns the Model with the given app_label and model_name". Maybe adding different `app_label`s to the Meta classes can do the trick ? (not very elegant)

Comment: I think it might be something to do with app registry, as you say. Here is my hack: I created a new app called `anotherapp`, left its `models.py` blank and added it to `INSTALLED_APPS`. Now, if I put `app_label = 'anotherapp'` in the `Meta` options for `Foobar`, then on `syncdb`, I get the desired behaviour after all, i.e. the tables are created and the `__name__`s of the models are correct.