# Can't get page to render. Django

Tags: python, django, render

It's strange. I know the url is finding the view, but it won't render the page/or anything...like print the HttpResponse. I'm at a lost troubleshooting. To me it seem like everything is connected, but somehow it isn't? Let me know if  you need any other information.

**urls.py** (project)

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('',         include('login_app.urls', namespace = "login_app")),    
    url(r'^CMIRS/', include('submit_app.urls', namespace = "submit_app")),  
]
```

**urls.py** (submit_app)

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'submit/$', views.submit, name ="submitView"),
]
```

**welcome.html** (login_app)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load staticfiles %} <!-- static files have to be loaded inside block content -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'login_app/css/welcome.css' %}" />

<div class="row">
    <a href="{% url 'submit_app:submitView' %}">
    <div class="col-sm-4 vcenter" style="text-align: center">
        <h1><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-3x"></i></h1>
        <h3>Report an Incident</h3>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    </a>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py** (submit_app)

```
from submit_app.forms import IncidentForm
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse

#@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def submit(request):
    print  ("made it")
    template = 'submit_app/submit.html'
    form = IncidentForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    #return render(request, template, context)
    return HttpResponse("view is working")
```

===================================================================
These were all done with `#@login_required(login_url='/login/')` commented out.

[image: just logged in][image: just clicked Report Incident][image: log]

Comment: What's the response code from your server log? Do you see any errors? What does your web page look like for the response?

Comment: Your submit app has the `login_required` decorator.  Is it redirecting you to the login app?  Is that app set up correctly?

Comment: @JohnGordon I also tried commenting the login decorator, but it was a no go.

Comment: @Shang Wang let me post two images that I think will be helpful

Comment: I would write `CMIRS`, lowercase, let us see your error page, and @JohnGordon is right, what for are you using `login_required` decorator?

Comment: why would CMIRS need to be lowercase? is it case sensitive?

Comment: I feel like i'm missing something stupid/fundamental.

Comment: So the `print  ("made it")` is not printed at all?

Comment: correct. it did not print, but the url tells me it's finding the view...idk

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515634/case-insensitive-urls-for-django, I think this is case sensitive related.

Comment: I keep "CMIRS" uppercase.... so even if it was case sensitive, I'm not sure that would be the issue. Unless you are thinking about something I'm not. I will try it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **urls.py** (project), do a little change, replace `''` with `r'^login/'`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/',  include('login_app.urls', namespace = "login_app")),    
    url(r'^CMIRS/', include('submit_app.urls', namespace = "submit_app")),  
]
```

When you are using a pattern `''`, everything will be matched to this url and you will never get to the view you want.

As you can see, both `/CMIRS/` and `/CMIRS/submit/` are directed to the login page (`welcome.html`). I guess you want to redirect user when they are not logged in or not typed a correct URL. Try to do the redirection in the view function.

I have checked the source code of `urlresovlers.py` in Django, it is using `re` module in python to do the regex match work. Here we can have a try:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match('', 'abc')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10bc46e68>
>>>
```

A match object returned means `'abc'` is regarded as a match for `''`. So when you put a `''` in the beginning of url patterns, everything will be "matched" with the empty string before it goes down to others.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly my problem. I didn't post my login_app urls, so you couldn't see, but adding `^login/` wasn't quite the right solution.....nevertheless the empty regex was the issue!