# Make all Django URLs case insensitive?

Tags: python, django

I'm working with a fairly large Django setup with 70+ applications within it.  One recent request is to make it work with case insensitive URLs.  Is there any way to get every app within it to use case insensitive URLs without having to alter the urls.py for each app?

It's a fairly straightforward process to get a single app to be case insensitive (e.g.: [Case insensitive urls for Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515634/case-insensitive-urls-for-django) ), but given the number of apps, is there a better (e.g.: middleware) way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Midddleware? Well you could redirect or change the request itself in [process_request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/topics/http/middleware/#process_request) to `lower(url)` or something more sophisticated. I would avoid doing so though, as with "70+ applications" you would create a significant additional load.
2. You could configure your webserver (nginx? apache?). I believe it's a good way to go.
3. You could [grep and sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169927/using-sed-and-grep-to-search-and-replace) your sources. In case your IDE doesn't provide such functionality. That's what I would definitely prefer.
4. You could wrap your `urlpatterns` into a method, that will apply `(?i)` in front of each regex (url pattern).
5. Of course you could always monkey-patch something. But this is a very, very ugly solution. Still, if you feel desperate, `LocaleRegexProvider.regex` in [urlresolvers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/core/urlresolvers/)