# Case insensitive URLS causes admin page error

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

In my Django site, I just made my urls case insensitive using

```py
re_path(r'^(?I)urlName', views.viewName)
```

But this caused an error when attempting to access my admin page, 
ValueError at /admin/
Non-reversible reg-exp portion: '(?i'

I have tried adding my admin page to my apps urls, my project urls, having admin not use re_patha and having an admin url in both the project and app urls.py

in project urls.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('interface.urls')),
]
```

in app urls.py:

```py
    from django.urls import path, re_path

    from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.indexView),
    re_path(r'^(?i)edit/', views.editView),
    re_path(r'^(?i)add/', views.addView),
    re_path(r'^(?i)delete/', views.deleteView),
    re_path(r'^(?i)postEditColumnData/', views.postEditTableData),
    re_path(r'^(?i)updateTableEdit/', views.postUpdateEdit),
    re_path(r'^(?i)postAdd/', views.postAdd),
    re_path(r'^(?i)postUploadFile/', views.postUploadFile),
    re_path(r'^(?i)postDelete/', views.postDelete),
    re_path(r'^(?i)postDelete/', views.postDelete),
    re_path(r'^(?i)postUploadDeleteFile/', views.postUploadDeleteFile),
    re_path(r'^(?i)uploadEditFile/', views.uploadEditFile),
    re_path(r'^(?i)denied/', views.authDenied),
]
```

How would I make this error go away, and is there a way to make the admin url case insensitive along with the other urls?

Comment: Why do you have 13 identical include lines in the project urls?

Comment: IDK for each url in the app, im new to Django. I guess I don't need all of them?

Comment: Well no, the whole point of `include` is that it includes all of the patterns in the linked file under the specified prefix.

Comment: Ok I removed them, but still getting the same error on admin

Comment: The admin page works if I remove all of the re_paths and make them just regular paths, but I am trying to have case insensitive urls

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51773173/2613005

Comment: When I try that I get a new error:

Reverse for 'app_list' with keyword arguments '{'app_label': 'auth'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/$(?i)(?P<app_label>auth|interface)/$']

Comment: Update: when I have re_path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls), I can access the admin page and all other other pages, but the admin page is case sensitive