# Case insensitive URLS in Django 3.0?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-urls

Is there a way to have case insensitive URLS with Django 2.0 and up syntax?

For example

`path('profile/<str:username>/add/',views.AddFriendRedirect.as_view(),name='add_friend'),`

If I did `profile/USERNAME`, when the username is username in all lowercase, how can I make it so that it 
is case insensitive? So that even uSErnAmE is valid

I know there are questions and answers out there for the old `url` syntax, but I would like to know if it is possilbe with the new `path` syntax

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Case insensitive urls for Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515634/case-insensitive-urls-for-django)

Comment: No, because I want to know if it is possible with the `path` syntax, not the `url` or `re_path` syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to have case insensitive URLS with Django 2.0 and up syntax?

In case the full url should be case insensitive, I don't see any other way than the answer in the [linked SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1515657/2549021). But what I gather from OP is that only the username part should be case insensitive. If we follow the solution with regex `(?i)`, this url will also be valid `PrOFile/UsERname/AdD`.

But it looks that OP only wants username comparison to be case insensitive. With the `str` converter, whatever is passed in url, will be passed as it is to the view. So in true sense, it is already case-insensitive. The suggested approach here should be that in the view one uses [`username__iexact`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#iexact) to get the user.

But, it we want that the username value passed to the view is in same format as required by the view e.g. lowercase, we can [register](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters) a custom path converter for this.

Because OP is originally using [string converter](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0367bc6d04ca6d1a4a21a69a839f6d404508f8df/django/urls/converters.py#L15), we could extend that and override `to_python` to convert value to lowercase. I am going with lowercase here because in OP it is mentioned that username is in lowercase.

```
class IStringConverter(StringConverter):

    def to_python(self, value):
        return value.lower()

# once done, register it as:
register_converter(IStringConverter, 'istr')

# and use it as:
path('profile/<istr:username>/add/',views.AddFriendRedirect.as_view(),name='add_friend'),
```

Comment: I assume this will work, however, even after doing the correct imports for StringConverter and register_converter, I am getting this error

`SyntaxError: trailing comma not allowed without surrounding parentheses`
and
`register_converter(IStringConverterr, 'istr')
NameError: name 'IStringConverterr' is not defined`

Comment: It looks like 1) you used `path` just like that. What I meant is that you should modify it in existing code wherever it was written earlier. 2) `IStringConverterr` is not defined  because there is a typo. At then end there is an extra `r`. I have fixed this in code.

Comment: I just realised I had made a typo
So your answer is correct. Thank you so much! I have been stuck on this all day

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to redirect non-lowercase paths to the lowercase path through a custom middleware.

Here's the middleware you want to add:

```
from django.contrib.redirects.middleware import RedirectFallbackMiddleware    

class CustomRedirectFallbackMiddleware(RedirectFallbackMiddleware):
    
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if response.status_code != 404:
            return response

        full_path = request.get_full_path()

        if not full_path.islower():
            return self.response_redirect_class(full_path.lower())
```